# How to set up weight based shipping through Australia Post in WP estore

Tags: php, wordpress, paypal

I have just created my wordpress website and wish to sell the soap etc that I make from it. I am a self taught web designer and have run into a problem with setting up the shipping. I need to be able to calculate postage through Australia Post using their priority post satchels. I would be looking at using both the 500g satchel and the 3kg satchel. I am using the  WP estore plugin for the product catalogue and will be using PayPal to accept payments for purchases plus shipping. I know I need to register with Australia Post to get their API, but that's as far as my knowledge goes. Can someone please advise me on what I need to do and how I need to set it up. My website is http://lynanne.com.au/.

Thanks in advance
Anne